# Looking for a scripting language

Tags: programming-languages, scripting-language

I'm looking for an embedable scripting language that is -

- compiled
- statically typed
- garbage collected
- lightweight and fast
- cross platform

Thanks.

Comment: Lua is probably the closest to what you want -- it fulfills all the criteria you listed except static typing. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/813926/strongly-typed-lua. You may have to roll your own preprocessor: http://blog.reverberate.org/2009/02/09/static-lua/. The only other language that has static typing and garbage collection is Objective-C 2.0, but it is not a embeddable scripting language.

Answer (score 1):

What about [Lua](http://www.lua.org/about.html)?

Answer (score 0):

[V8](http://code.google.com/p/v8/) is:

- JIT-compiled
- [embeddable](http://code.google.com/apis/v8/embed.html)
- [fast](http://shootout.alioth.debian.org/u32/javascript.php)
- [garbage collected](http://code.google.com/apis/v8/design.html#garb_coll)
- cross-platform, as evidenced by the fact that Chrome is on Windows, Linux and Mac

Answer (score 0):

Try the Squirrel programming language
http://www.squirrel-lang.org/

If you can remove "statically typed" from requirements and use a Dynamic language then i would recommend the Ring programming language
http://ring-lang.net